# Finding how many users have table creation privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find out how many users have permission to create a table in my Oracle 11g database by using meta data.

What kind of query should I write? (I don't want it to be very complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All users and roles who has such privilege:

```
select *
from dba_sys_privs
where privilege = 'CREATE TABLE' or privilege = 'CREATE ANY TABLE';
```

Also you need view DBA_ROLE_PRIVS because user can get privilege indirectly, using role.

Comment: This will not work in most environments.  Privileges like these are usually combined into a role and then the role is granted to users.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct usr) 
from (
  select auth, tp, connect_by_root auth usr, connect_by_root tp tp_usr
  from (
    select null grantee, username auth, 'user' tp from dba_users
    union
    select grantee, granted_role, 'role' from dba_role_privs
    union
    select grantee, privilege, 'priv' from dba_sys_privs
  )
  start with grantee is null
  connect by grantee = prior auth
) where tp_usr = 'user' and auth in ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE ANY TABLE');
```

This query also scans granted roles recursively. However, I'm still not sure that it gives all the users who can create a table.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see what you tried so far. May I let you try first using the following :

`dba_users` and `dba_sys_privs`.

The privilege you are looking for is `CREATE ANY TABLE`.

Please search for them and come up with your try,and I would be happy to help you further.